# JavaScript filter that returns a match for "A B C" when query is "A C"

Tags: javascript

Given a JSON array of objects:

```
`[ 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "full_name": "John T Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "full_name": "John T. Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "full_name": "Jon Dough"
  }
]`
```

Without doing a for loop, is it possible to filter this list so that given a search query of "John Doe", it returns a filtered array consisting of records 1-3 as matches but not 4?

When the search query is "John Doe" a match exists if either "John" or "Doe" appears in the object collection.

Comment: `JSON.parse(data).filter(...)`

Comment: Not really, I mean that whether you use a typical loop or Array methods your code will still have to iterate over Array-element. Also, is that really JSON, or is it an Array of Objects? Both are fine, but since it's not wrapped in quotes (for example: `'[{"prop":"val"},{"prop":2}]'`) it doesn't *look* like JSON.

Comment: “*Without doing a for loop…*” Do you mind elaborating on what exactly makes you averse to iterating this data structure…?

Comment: @esqew - I'm just trying to learn alternative methods vs iterative programming.

Comment: @jcoder the algorithm is a fundamental paradigm of any modern programming language. Also, you should post the JavaScript you've attempted to use as a [mcve]. ATTM your question is a request for us to write the code for you.

Comment: Odd requirements about iteration not withstanding, the application of the _"search term"_ is unclear. Free text matching is a very broad topic and without very specific rules on how you expect it to be applied, this question needs more focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case you can utilize the array objects `.filter` function in combination with a regular expression. As you're interested in the words `John` and `Doe`, the regular expression `/\b(?:John|Doe)\b/` executed on a string will return a result if either the word John or Doe are present.

```js
let arr = JSON.parse(`[{
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "John "
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "full_name": "John T Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "full_name": "John T. Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "full_name": "Jon Dough"
    }
]`);

console.log(arr.filter(element => element.full_name.match(/\b(?:John|Doe)\b/)));
```